# Collaborative filtering cypher with attributes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, collaborative-filtering

I am using neo4j to setup a recommender system. I have the following setup:

**Nodes:**

- Users
- Movies
- Movie attributes (e.g. genre)

**Relationships**

- `(m:Movie)-[w:WEIGHT {weight: 10}]->(a:Attribute)`
- `(u:User)-[r:RATED {rating: 5}]->(m:Movie)`

Here is a diagram of how it looks:

[image]

I am now trying to figure out how to apply a collaborative filtering scheme that works as follows:

1. Checks which attributes the `user` has liked (implicitly by liking the movies)
2. Find similar `other users` that have liked these similar attributes
3. Recommend the top movies to the `user`, which the user has NOT seen, but similar `other users` have seen.

The condition is obviously that each attribute has a certain weight for each movie. E.g. the genre `adventure` can have a weight of `10` for the Lord of Rings but a weight of `5` for the Titanic.

In addition, the system needs to take into account the ratings for each movies. E.g. if `other user` has rated Lord of the Rings `5`, then his/her attributes of the Lord of Ranges are scaled by `5` and not `10`. The `user` that has rated the implicit attributes also close to `5` should then get this movie recommended as opposed to another user that has rated similar attributes higher.

I made a start by simply recommending only other movies that other users have rated, but I am not sure how to take into account the relationships RATING and WEIGHT. It also did not work:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:RATED]->(movie1)<-[:RATED]-(ouser:User),
         (ouser)-[:RATED]->(movie2)<-[:RATED]-(oouser:User)
WHERE user.uid = "user4"
AND   NOT    (user)-[:RATED]->(movie2)
RETURN oouser
```

Comment: Can you post some use cases to clarify how to answer your 3 questions / business logic?

Comment: Movie ratings? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: _Find similar other users that have liked these similar attributes_: What is your similarity criteria? If a user likes a movie with attribute "Adventure" and other user likes another movie with the same attribute these users are similar? These similarity depends on weight of the attribute?

Comment: Yes exactly! So indeed we need a similarity criteria, based on the attribute weight of the movies that the user liked AND the weight of the rating of the user for that attribute. E.g. rating * attr. weight = score for attribute from a user

Comment: But based on this criteria, if a "user 1" rated with 2 a "Movie a" with attribute adventure = 10 (2x10=20) and another "user 2" rated rated with 10 a "Movie b" with attribute adventure = 2 (10x2=20) these users are considered very similar. Make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for, mathematically speaking, is a simplified [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) between two users. That is, how similar are they based on how many things they have in common. I say simplified because we are not taking into account the movies they disagree about. Essentially, and following your order, it would be:

1) Get the total weight of every Attribute for every user. For instance:

```
MATCH (user:User{name:'user1'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[r:RATED]->(m:Movie)->[w:WEIGHT]->(a:Attribute)
WITH user, r.rating * w.weight AS totalWeight, a
WITH user, a, sum(totalWeight) AS totalWeight
```

We need the last line because we had a row for each Movie-Attribute combination

2) Then, we get users with similar tastes. This is a performance danger zone, some filtering might be neccesary. But brute forcing it, we get users that like each attribute within an 10% error (for instance)

```
WITH user, a, totalWeight*0.9 AS minimum, totalWeight*1.10 AS maximum
MATCH (a)<-[w:WEIGHT]-(m:Movie)<-[r:RATES]-(otherUser:User)
WITH user, a, otherUser
WHERE w.weight * r.rating > minimum AND w.weight * r.rating < maximum
WITH user, otherUser
```

So now we have a row (unique because of last line) with any otherUser that is a match. Here, to be honest, I would need to try to be sure if otherUsers with only 1 genre match would be included.. if they are, an additional filter would be needed. But I think that should go after we get this going.

3) Now it´s easy:

```
MATCH (otherUser)-[r:RATES]->(m:Movie)
WHERE NOT (user)-[:RATES]->(m)
RETURN m, sum(r.rating) AS totalRating ORDER BY totalRating DESC
```

As mentioned before, the tricky part is 2), but after we know how to get the math going, it should be easier. Oh, and about math, for it to work properly, total weights for a movie should sum 1 ([normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics))). In any other case, the difference between total weights for movies would cause an unfair comparison.

I wrote this without proper studying (paper, pencil, equations, statistics) and trying the code in a sample dataset. I hope it can help you anyway!

In case you want this recommendation without taking into account user ratings or attribute weights, it should be enough to substitute the math in lines in 1) and 2) with just r.rating or w.weight, respectively. RATES and WEIGHTS relationships would still be used, so for instance an avid consumer of Adventure movies would be recommended Movies by consumers of Adventure movies, but not modified by ratings or by attribute weight, as we chose.

EDIT: Code edited to fix syntax errors discussed in comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot; this is amazing so far. I am struggling now with the last line in 2). The distinct seems not to work, actually it says that the syntax is incorrect. Unknown function 'distinct'

Comment: Another error: Cannot use aggregation in ORDER BY if there are no aggregate expressions in the preceding RETURN

Comment: This was my mistake. Apparently (https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/6545 ) there are some cases where distinct do not work if it makes no difference to apply it. I would try "WITH user, otherUser", since aggregating on a should make the trick and anyway we don´t want to differentiate by Attribute at that line. In case there are duplicated otherUser, then try "WITH user, distinct(otherUser) as otherUser" and it should work. Sorry for the uncertainty, I still struggle with this kind of use cases on Cypher sometimes!

Comment: About the last error, change the last line to RETURN m, sum(r.rating) AS totalRating ORDER BY totalRating DESC . When we fix these last syntax errors I will edit the answer.

Comment: Awesome. I changed the last line, and dropped the Distinct and replaced it with your suggestion, and now it works. It basically returns only the items that have been rated by others. Really really goood!!

Comment: I am considering to set out a bonus bounty for additional cyphers for pure Content-Based Filtering (attributes only) and Collaborative Filtering (ratings of users only). I think that your answer is an excellent starting point. Can a second bounty be given to someone?

Comment: I´m not sure I understand. I think you will have no problems asking a second Question here and assigning a bounty to it. And if you are asking me if I agree to my answer being used as a starting point for anyone else to answer, by linking it there, I absolutely have no problem with it :-)

Comment: Well, I am also looking for pure collaborative filtering (attributes only) and pure content-based (user similarity only) filtering. Do you think you could add this to your answer for an additional bounty?

Comment: I modified the answer (second to last paragraph) to add option of using purely user ratings or attribute weights. In any case we calculate user similarity to be able to recommend more movies. I think adding depth to  filtering options (for instance, only movies with those attributes, in any order, or calculating similarity by just similar movies) is a work that sould be discussed outside here since the scope can grow quite a lot and the business logic should be clarified. There are many possible desired outcomes.

Since it´s such a small addition, I think no bounty should be given :-)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your 1st query:

**Checks which attributes the user has liked (implicitly by liking the movies)**

```
MATCH (user:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[r:RATED]->(m:movie)
OPTIONAL MATCH (m)-[r:RATED]->(a:Attribute)
WHERE user.uid = "user4"
RETURN user, collect ({ a:a.title })
```

It is a subquery construct where in you find the movies rated by the user and then find attributes of the movies and finally return list of liked attributes

you can modify return statement to ***collect (a) as attributes*** if you need entire node

Comment: Hmm, where do you include the weighting and the ratings?